# How do I test for Web SQL exceptions?

Tags: qunit, web-sql

Posted on the jQuery forums http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-test-for-web-sql-exceptions but thought I'd ask here.  I'm trying to write unit tests against Web SQL api that I'm developing.  The scenario I'm trying to account for is when parameters are not being supplied.  Below is some sample code:

Web SQL helper object:

```
var sql = function () {
return {
    getDb: function () {            
        return openDatabase("sampleDb", "1.0", "sampleDb", 5 * 1024 * 1024);
    },

    initDb: function () {
        var db = this.getDb();
        if (db) {
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SampleTable (Key TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,Value TEXT NOT NULL)");
            });
        }
    },

    insertRecord: function (key, value) {
        var db = this.getDb();
        if (db) {
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO SampleTable (Key, Value) VALUES (?, ?)", [key, value],
                    function () {
                    },
                    function (tx, error) {
                        throw (error.message);
                    });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

}();

Below is my unit test:

```
asyncTest("test1", function () {
raises(function () {
    sql.initDb();
    sql.insertRecord(null, null);
    start();
},
"exception expected");
```

});

I'm expecting an exception to be thrown because the key and value parameters are not being supplied; however, when the test is finished executing, it says that no exception is thrown.  While I'm not explicitly throwing an exception, one is raised because the dynamically generated sql statement can not be executed without supplying the key and value parameters.

Is it possible to write tests to account for these types of scenarios?

Comment: It looks like there are two ways of testing for errors.  throws (http://api.qunitjs.com/throws/) and raises (http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/raises).

Answer (score 0):

Why not test async exception test first? As far I see, your test is nothing to do with WebSQL.

Also qunit async test may require `expect()` before calling `start()`. If not, all test are just passed, without waiting async workflow.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying.  I've updated the code sample so that the call to insertRecord throws an error.  The test actually involves Web SQL because calling insertRecord should throw an exception which is raised in the error callback hander:  function (tx, error) {
  throw (error.message);
})

Comment: I means insertRecord function should be replace by simple async and test it first. For example: `insertRecord = function() {setTimeout(function(throw 'e');)}`